# Turn number into day of week - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this data:

```
data = [{"day":0,"count":1.0},{"day":1,"count":1.1666666666666667},{"day":2,"count":2.625},{"day":3,"count":2.0},{"day":4,"count":3.8},{"day":5,"count":1.2},{"day":6,"count":41.666666666666664}]
```

I've tried a couple different ways, but can't figure it out. Is there a way to turn the day integer into a day of the week (e.g. "Sunday" is 0), and then have them start at Monday, so the end result would be:

```
[{"day":"Monday","count":1.1666666666666667},{"day":"Tuesday","count":2.625},{"day":"Wednesday","count":2.0},{"day":"Thursday","count":3.8},{"day":"Friday","count":1.2},{"day":"Saturday","count":41.666666666666664}, {"day":"Sunday","count":1.0}]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your using the ruby 1.9 hash syntax for symbols as keys, but with strings as keys. So either lose all of the quotes around your `"day"` and `"count"` and make them `date: 0, count: 1.0` also be sure you have a space after the colon. Or use the old style `"day" => 0, "count" => 1.0`.

Comment: Well it's not valid `ruby` because it's `JSON`

Comment: @user2270029 how is this code being used? Give some more background so answers can be tailored towards the environment you are working in. There are multiple ways to do this, and the answer below only works with some translating between a Hash and JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
require 'json'
require 'date'

data = '[{"day":0,"count":1.0},{"day":1,"count":1.1666666666666667},{"day":2,"count":2.625},{"day":3,"count":2.0},{"day":4,"count":3.8},{"day":5,"count":1.2},{"day":6,"count":41.666666666666664}]'

dates = JSON.parse(data).rotate.map do |hsh| 
          week_day = Date::DAYNAMES[hsh["day"]]
          { "day" => week_day, "count" => hsh["count"]  }
        end

puts dates.to_json

#=> [{"day":"Monday","count":1.1666666666666667},{"day":"Tuesday","count":2.625},{"day":"Wednesday","count":2.0},{"day":"Thursday","count":3.8},{"day":"Friday","count":1.2},{"day":"Saturday","count":41.666666666666664},{"day":"Sunday","count":1.0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the predefined `DAYNAMES` array in the Date module.

```
require 'date'
data.map! { |element| element[:day] = Date::DAYNAMES.rotate[element[:day]] }
```

This will convert your integer into a named day starting with Monday as zero.

Comment: It's giving me this result ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday",null]

Comment: Sorry for the error. I was mistaken; the index starts at zero. Fixing the answer now.

Comment: Adding rotate will allow for the constant array to start at Monday instead of Sunday as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

The `data` var that you are showing is actually `JSON` which means you must `require 'json'` so that ruby is able to parse it.

Next we `require 'date'` so that we can use ruby to convert your days from numbers to words.

Lastly we convert the `data` object back to `JSON` so that you can use it however it was intended.

```
require 'date'
require 'json'

day = Proc.new { |d| Date::DAYNAMES[d] }

data = '[ {"day":0,"count":1.0},
          {"day":1,"count":1.1666666666666667},
          {"day":2,"count":2.625},
          {"day":3,"count":2.0},
          {"day":4,"count":3.8},
          {"day":5,"count":1.2},
          {"day":6,"count":41.666666666666664} ]'

new_data = JSON.parse(data).map do |n| 
  { "day" => day.call(n["day"]), "count" => n["count"]  }.to_json
end

puts new_data
```